# Ограничить количество выводимых символов mysql pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код которым вывожу данные из таблицы:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
    $db   = '';
    $user = '';
    $pass = ';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM task order by id_t desc');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<div class='cont' style='height:auto;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;'>
    <table style='text-align:center;'>
    <tr>
    <td><span style='font-size: 10px;font-weight: bold;color: #777;'>ОПИСАНИЕ</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>".$row['desc_t']."</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div><br> \n";
}
?>
```

Как можно ограничить количество символов выводимой информации `".$row['desc_t']."`

Comment: `<td>" . mb_substr($row['desc_t'], 0, 5) . "</td>` где __0__ - позиция первого символа, а __5__ - длина подстроки. Если работаете с латиницей, то приставку `mb_` можно опустить.

Comment: @Эдуард спасибо большое, все работает.